# How to avoid inconsistent data in PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I have just started to use Npgsql to access PostgreSQL through C#.

I access the database to get data but also to modify data.

I deal with Radiotherapy clinical trials.
Each trial has a variable number of related RT structures.
Trial names and RT structure names are stored in separate tables linked through keys.

When I delete a trial, I have to delete all its RT structures as well.
I delete the RT structures first and then I delete the trial itself.
The whole task requires two database accesses to update two tables.
How can I know from my C# script that the first table has been updated before proceeding to update the second one?
If I do not make any check I might end up having inconsistent data in the database.
For example, a deleted trial whose RT structures have not been deleted and bear no relation to any 'live' trial.
How can I tackle such a problem with Npgsql?

Comment: Do one batch with `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT`. Also use foreign keys, and delete from the child table first, or use `ON DELETE CASCADE`

Comment: Whenever you post a question, make sure you mention your own efforts at the trials you did

Answer (score 0):

Perform the operations required in a single transaction. This will ensure that both operations get applied successfully. If either transaction fails, it should rollback so that data integrity is maintained.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Another option would bee to not delete from RT at all. I assume there is a FK from RT  to the Trial. (If there is not then you do not have data integrity anyway, so add it). Make sure the definition of the FK contains `on delete cascade`. Now you just delete the Trial, the data base manager (ie Postgres) will automatically take care of the RT rows. This way Postgres guarantees there are no orphaned RT rows.

Comment: Thank you. That sounds like a good idea.

Comment: Thank you. That sounds like a good idea. There is an fk from table rt_structure to trial.   How can I add the "on delete cascade"?  Thank you